# How to Convert string("1.0000") to int

Tags: c#, string, int, valueconverter

The string format data with mostly 4 decimal places needs to be converted into int.
I have tried this one but does not work and even directly using this Convert.ToInt16() but still did not worked:

```
Int32 result;
bool status = Int32.TryParse(v, out result);
```

Is there other ways to convert this?

Thanks.

Comment: Try using Convert.ToInt32().

Comment: Why don't you use `decimal.TryParse`?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You can convert it to Double first, and then convert to Int32

```
String s = "1.0000";
Double temp;

Boolean isOk = Double.TryParse(s, out temp);

Int32 value = isOk ? (Int32) temp : 0;
```

Answer (score 3):

You can use the following:

```
string data = "1.0000";
int number
if(data.Contains('.'))
    number = int.Parse(data.Substring(0, data.IndexOf('.'))); //Contains decimal separator
else
    number = int.Parse(data); //Contains only numbers, no decimal separator.
```

Because `1.0000` has decimal places, first strip those from the `string`, and then parse the string to `int`.

Comment: Throws an exception if there is no point (or comma instead), and also interprets `10.000.000` as 10 instead of 10 million (with point as group separator)

Comment: @TimSchmelter the question is about a number with a point as decimal separator. This means that the culture is so that a point will not be a group separator. I agree with lack of point, will improve

Answer (score 1):

You have to parse it as decimal and then cast to int.

```
decimal resultTmp;
bool status = Decimal.TryParse("1.000".Replace(".",","), out resultTmp);
int result = (int)resultTmp;
```

Also change '.' to ','

Comment: why change '.' to ','? this would depend on the culture.

Comment: yes, its better to give CurrentCulture as argument. I had to change it because in mine it is not correct format.